# 2015 Audi w/ Lane Assist The steering wheel sticks around center while driving on the free way

Tags: steering, audi

I have a 2015 Audi S3 w/ Lane Assist.  With lane assist off.  Sometimes while cold, sometimes after 20+ miles the steering wheel at freeway speeds will stick in the center. It's like it fights you a little bit right around center.

Any ideas?

Comment: Immediate idea:  Don't drive it.  Have a flatbed take it to the dealer for service.  I'd be pretty freaked out if an electric motor was fighting me for control.

Comment: This is a question for the stealership. No way I'd continue to drive something were the steering 'sticks' at all, especially not a new vehicle.

Comment: Absolutely agree with the two above comments. Don't fight it ... get it fixed under warranty which seeing as how its less than a year old, should have plenty of warranty left.

Comment: Thanks. Currently, I'm getting the "we can't replicate it" from the dealer.  If anyone runs into this, has an idea of what it is, that would be great.  If I figure it out I'll post it here to.

Comment: Which Audi is this? Does it have electric steering? Does the voiceover in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7jsYcYOByA) capture what you're experiencing? It looks like many owners are [complaining of gremlins](http://www.audiworld.com/forums/a6-c7-platform-discussion-194/audi-electric-steering-issue-reports-consolidated-2844976/) with the electric steering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this issue is caused by one of two things.

1. Bad steering sensors that are mounted on the rack
2. Steering sensors need to be 'aligned'

Problem seems to be that the sensors in the steering rack that tell the electric assist motor the position of the wheels and which way to boost the steering, left or right, are out of alignment. So there a sub-second delay in the boost, which causes the notchy feel to the steering.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: A reference would be great.

Answer (score 2):

After referencing the comments above and taking it into a different dealer, I had it confirmed that it was the rack.

It is a ***known*** issue with Audi's electric steering.

They fixed it by replacing the rack.